# Switch between two different apps?

Tags: python, kivy

Is it possible in Python Kivy to switch back and forth between two different APPS of different physical sizes (icon size and fullscreen) via respectively clicking a button?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class FirstApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        button = Button(text='Schließen und Zweite App starten')
        button.bind(on_press=self.switch_to_second_app)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        return layout

    def switch_to_second_app(self, instance):
        self.stop()  # Schließt die erste App
        SecondApp().run()  # Startet die zweite App


class SecondApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        button = Button(text='Zurück zur Ersten App')
        button.bind(on_press=self.switch_to_first_app)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        return layout

    def switch_to_first_app(self, instance):
        self.stop()  # Schließt die zweite App
        FirstApp().run()  # Startet die erste App


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FirstApp().run()
```

It doesn't work that way because you probably can't reopen an app directly in the same main loop(?) on an Android device (on a computer it works). Is there a solution?